# How do you store the access token in your browser for the next api access point in node.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I'd like to know how I can use the access token I got to access the next api end point protected by auth. To be more specific, how can I use that Authorization bearer thing to store token in my browser like the code below.

I know you can store the access token in the web storage or cookie which I will figure out how to do later.(or you can help me figure it out now) What I am wondering now is that after I retrive token from the storage, how can I actually put it inside the header to use it?(and delete it when log out.
Thank you very much guys for help.

```
HTTP/1.1

GET /stars/pollux
Host: galaxies.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsI.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczotcGxlL.mFrs3Zo8eaSNcxiNfvRh9dqKP4F1cB
```

Comment: Are you asking how to store the token (which would be [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) or are you asking how to put it in the headers for a request.  The question in your title doesn't match the question in the text.  Examples of setting custom headers using the `fetch()` api [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: jfriend00, I am asking how to put it in the headers for the next request and thank you for help.

Comment: jfriend00, Could you just show me the example code?

Comment: There's an example of setting a custom header right there in the documentation I linked to.  What part of that do you not understand?  I could just copy that doc example to an answer, but it would be better if you explained what you tried and didn't work or what part of that example you don't understand.